# How to protect specific sheets if they exist?

Tags: excel, vba, password-protection

I have code that runs on files in a loop.

I need to protect some tabs which may not exist in the files.

It would be something like this:

```vb
Sub AtualizarCOFAGRO()
    
    'this sets your template workbook/worksheet
    Dim copyWB As Workbook
    Dim copyWS As Worksheet
    Dim rInfo As Range
    
    Set copyWB = Workbooks("Atualização de COF")
    Set copyWS = copyWB.Sheets("Cadastro COF")
    Set rInfo = copyWS.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(copyWS.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row, Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column)) 'copiar todas as linhas e colunas com valores do arquivo
    
    'this creates a collection of all filenames to be processed
    Dim loopFolder As String
    Dim fileNm As Variant
    Dim myFiles As New Collection
    
    'Optimize Macro Speed
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
    '''don't forget the backslash before the final double-quote below
    
    loopFolder = "J:\Files\Dept Produtos\Testes Macro Simulador\Arquivos para atualização\"
    fileNm = Dir(loopFolder & "*.xlsm")
    
    Do While fileNm <> ""
        myFiles.Add fileNm
        fileNm = Dir
    Loop
        
    'this loops through all filenames and copies your copyWS to the beginning
    
    Dim wb As Workbook
    For Each fileNm In myFiles
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=(loopFolder & fileNm))
        wb.Unprotect "Senha453" 'desbloquear planilha
       
        wb.Sheets("infomacro").Range("B2").ClearContents
        wb.Sheets("Cadastro COF").Cells.Clear 'limpar toda planilha dos arquivos abertos no loop
        rInfo.Copy
        wb.Sheets("Cadastro COF").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
        wb.Sheets("infomacro").Range("B2").Value = Date
        wb.Sheets("infomacro").Range("B2").NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
        wb.Sheets("infomacro").Visible = False
        wb.Sheets("Cadastro COF").Visible = False
        
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        
        wb.Protect "Senha453" 'bloquear planilha
```

This is the part I can't solve:

The name of the sheet could be "input dados" or "CDC" or "LEASING". I would like to protect any that exist. If not continue to next line.

```vb
        wb.Sheets("input dados").Protect "Senha453"
        ' **or**
        wb.Sheets("LEASING").Protect "Senha453"
        ' **or**
        wb.Sheets("CDC").Protect "Senha453"
```

Then follows

```vb
        Calculate
        wb.Save
        
        Dim inf As Worksheet
        Dim name As String
        Dim savefolder As String
        
        Set inf = wb.Sheets("Cadastro COF")
        savefolder = "J:\Files\Dept Produtos\Testes Macro Simulador\Atualizados\"
        name = wb.Sheets("infomacro").Range("b3").Value
        
        wb.SaveAs Filename:=savefolder & name & ".xlsm"
        wb.Close
    Next

    'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.AskToUpdateLinks = Trueele
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is possible, you can simply use something like this:

```
On Error Resume Next
wb.Sheets("input dados").Protect "Senha453"
wb.Sheets("LEASING").Protect "Senha453"
wb.Sheets("CDC").Protect "Senha453"
On Error goto 0 'Or any other error management
```

If the worksheet exist, it will protect it. If not, it will simply move to the next line. You can check if the workbook actually exists, but this will take more time to run, so unless you actually need to know if it exists or not, the above code should do it.
If you need to verify if it exist, it would be something like this:

```
dim ws as Worksheet
dim exist as Boolean
exist = False
For Each ws in wb.Worksheets
  If ws.Name= "NameYouWantToFind"
     exist = True
  End If
Next ws
```

After that, you could simply use another if with the exist as condition.

Let me know if it worked.

Comment: Thanks @Daniel Fittipaldi, it worked perfectly. Simpler than I was trying to formulate.